# mariadb not using the correct index with subquery

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm facing a performance issue on a mariadb database. It seems to me that mariadb is not using the correct index when doing a request with a subquery, while injecting manually the result of the subquery in the request successfully uses the index:

Here is the request with bad behavior (note that the second subquery reads more rows than necessary):

```
ANALYZE SELECT  `orders`.* FROM `orders` 
  WHERE `orders`.`account_id` IN (SELECT `accounts`.`id` FROM `accounts` WHERE `accounts`.`user_id` = 88144) 
  AND (               orders.type not in ("LimitOrder", "MarketOrder")
                   OR orders.type     in ("LimitOrder", "MarketOrder") AND orders.state <> "canceled"
                   OR orders.type     in ("LimitOrder", "MarketOrder") AND orders.state =  "canceled" AND orders.traded_btc > 0 ) 
  AND (NOT (orders.type = 'AdminOrder' AND orders.state = 'canceled'))  ORDER BY `orders`.`id` DESC LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0 \G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: PRIMARY
        table: accounts
         type: ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,index_accounts_on_user_id
          key: index_accounts_on_user_id
      key_len: 4
          ref: const
         rows: 7
       r_rows: 7.00
     filtered: 100.00
   r_filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: PRIMARY
        table: orders
         type: ref
possible_keys: index_orders_on_account_id_and_type,index_orders_on_type_and_state_and_buying,index_orders_on_account_id_and_type_and_state,index_orders_on_account_id_and_type_and_state_and_traded_btc
          key: index_orders_on_account_id_and_type_and_state_and_traded_btc
      key_len: 4
          ref: bitcoin_central.accounts.id
         rows: 60
       r_rows: 393.86
     filtered: 100.00
   r_filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using index condition; Using where
```

When manually injecting the result of the subquery I have the correct behaviour (and expected performance):

```
ANALYZE SELECT  `orders`.* FROM `orders`      
    WHERE `orders`.`account_id` IN (433212, 433213, 433214, 433215, 436058, 436874, 437950)
    AND (               orders.type not in ("LimitOrder", "MarketOrder")                           
                     OR orders.type     in ("LimitOrder", "MarketOrder") AND orders.state <> "canceled"
                     OR orders.type     in ("LimitOrder", "MarketOrder") AND orders.state =  "canceled" AND orders.traded_btc > 0 )
   AND (NOT (orders.type = 'AdminOrder' AND orders.state = 'canceled')) 
   ORDER BY `orders`.`id` DESC LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: orders
         type: range
possible_keys: index_orders_on_account_id_and_type,index_orders_on_type_and_state_and_buying,index_orders_on_account_id_and_type_and_state,index_orders_on_account_id_and_type_and_state_and_traded_btc
          key: index_orders_on_account_id_and_type_and_state_and_traded_btc
      key_len: 933
          ref: NULL
         rows: 2809
       r_rows: 20.00
     filtered: 100.00
   r_filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using index condition; Using where; Using filesort
1 row in set (0.37 sec)
```

Note that I have exactly the same issue when JOINing the two tables.

Here is an extract of the definitions of my orders table:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE orders \G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: orders
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `orders` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `account_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `traded_btc` decimal(16,8) DEFAULT '0.00000000',
  `type` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `state` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `index_orders_on_account_id_and_type_and_state_and_traded_btc` (`account_id`,`type`,`state`,`traded_btc`),
  CONSTRAINT `orders_account_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`account_id`) REFERENCES `accounts` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8575594 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Does anyone know what's going on here?
Is there a way to force the database to use my index in my subrequest.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit more....your analyze plan looks good on both cases...in your first case you have two queries, and in your second just one query!

Comment: I do not see a "second subquery" in the first `SELECT`.

Comment: What index do you think it should be using?

Answer (score 2):

`IN ( SELECT ... )` optimizes poorly.  The usual solution is to turn into a `JOIN`:

```
FROM accounts AS a
JOIN orders AS o  ON a.id = o.account_id
WHERE a.user_id = 88144
  AND ... -- the rest of your WHERE
```

Or is that what you did with "Note that I have exactly the same issue when JOINing the two tables."?  If so, let's see the query and it's `EXPLAIN`.

You refer to "expected performance"...  Are you referring to the numbers in the `EXPLAIN`?  Or do you have timings to back up the assertion?

I like to do this to get a finer grained look into how much "work" is going on:

```
FLUSH STATUS;
SELECT ...;
SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';
```

Those numbers usually make it clear whether a table scan was involved or whether the query stopped after `OFFSET+LIMIT`.  The numbers are exact counts, unlike `EXPLAIN`, which is just estimates.

Presumably you usually look in `orders` via `account_id`?  Here is a way to speed up such queries:

Replace the current two indexes

```
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `account_id__type__state__traded_btc` 
    (`account_id`,`type`,`state`,`traded_btc`),
```

with these:

```
 PRIMARY KEY (`account_id`, `type`, `id`),
 KEY (id)  -- to keep AUTO_INCREMENT happy.
```

This clusters all the rows for a given account, thereby making the queries run faster, especially if you are *now* I/O-bound.  If some combination of columns makes a "natural" PK, then toss `id` completely.

(And notice how I shortened your key name without losing *any* info?)

Also, if you are I/O-bound, shrinking the table is quite possible by turning those lengthy `VARCHARs` (state & type) into `ENUMs`.

**More**

Given that the query involves

```
WHERE ... mess with INs and ORs ...
ORDER BY ...
LIMIT 20
```

*and* there are 2 million rows for that one user, there is no `INDEX` that can get past the `WHERE` to  get into the `ORDER BY` so that it can consume the `LIMIT`.  That is, it *must* perform this way:

1. filter through the 2M rows for that one user
2. sort (`ORDER BY`) some significant fraction of 2M rows
3. peel off 20 rows.  (Yeah, 5.6 uses a "priority" queue, making the sort O(1) instead of O(log N), but this is not that much help.

I'm actually amazed that the `IN( constants )` worked well.

Comment: Thanks for your response. the command `SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';`is quite usefull. Effectively, after some more analyze the slowing part of the request is the comparison of the string fields. Unfortunately, we can't easily modify our ORM to deal with ENUMS, isn't there a way to optimize the search while keeping VARCHAR fields?

Comment: `ENUM` would especially shine when the table becomes too huge to fit in cache.  You have 8M rows?  I can't tell if how big the table is _or will be_.  Etc.  Meanwhile, we can focus on optimizing with `VARCHARs`.

Comment: Yes, we have 8M rows, and we start having performance issues with account ids having lots of orders.

Comment: How much RAM?  What is the setting of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  How many orders might one account_id have?

Comment: We have 32 Gb of RAM and a user can have up to 2 Million orders and our `innodb_buffer_pool_size`= 23587717120.

Comment: And the buffer_pool is a reasonable fraction of the RAM -- good.  But the user with 2M orders (upwards of 1GB) is an issue.

Comment: I added to my answer; alas, still no "real" solution.

Comment: OK Thanks for your help, I'll search for an alternative solution using virtual colums.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Please use inner join instead of in-subquery.

Comment: Why should we use INNER JOIN? Does this provide a performance increase?